# Eclipse Memory Analyzer: Unable to attach to 32-bit process

Tags: memory, 32bit-64bit, analyzer

when trying to acquire a Heapdump of my eclispe rcp application with the Java Memory Analayzer I get the following error message:

```
Error creating heap dump. jmap exit code = 1
4120: Unable to attach to 32-bit process running under WOW64
The -F option can be used when the target process is not responding
```

OS: 64bit Windows7

Java Memory Analyzer: 64bit

Application: 32bit

I tried the 32 and the 64 bit variation and got the same error.

Cans oemone tell me what the problem is?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This means that the jmap you are using is the one that is bundled with the 64 bit version of the JDK. If you are using this jmap to acquire a heap dump from a 32 bit JVM, then this error pops up.

Solution : Use the version of jmap that is bundled with the 32 bit JDK.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. @suhrick could you explain further what you mean? I don't see how to change the jmap to use (since it's the one embedded in the Memory Analyzer of Eclipse).

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have Java 64 bit version(so is for Java tools like jvisualvm and jstack) and the IDE/path, where ever you run javac command have java 32 bit in class path, then you will see such issues.
if you try to analyze this process from

1)java VisualVM, then it may not load your process properly, means you will not able to take thread/heap dumps for problematic process.

2) from jstack , then also it will create same problem like you mentioned above.

To solve the issue,make sure that everything is matched in the version.